# Parsing date time in D3.js

Tags: parsing, d3.js, time-format

I'm trying to parse the date time value from .csv file in D3.js, but for some reason I keep getting null. Here's what I have,

.csv data:

```
"","date","count"
"1","2011-11-15 02:00:01",1
"2","2011-11-15 02:00:02",2
"3","2011-11-15 02:00:03",1
"4","2011-11-15 02:00:04",1
"5","2011-11-15 02:00:05",1
"6","2011-11-15 02:00:07",1

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%I:%M %p").parse;
```

When I do `console.log(parseDate(d.date))`, I get null. I also tried `console.log(parseDate(d.date.toString()))`, but I still get null. Why is it not parsing?

Comment: You're not passing the correct time format for your data to d3. D3 is expecting `%I` - hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number [01,12], `%M` - minute as a decimal number [00,59] followed by `%p` - either AM or PM. Try `var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;` and have a read of the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting)

Comment: @user1614080 Thanks for the comment. I realized that later on as I was testing it in chrome console. Sorry for such a trivial question and forgetting to remove it.